# How can I measure the network traffic used by one command?

Tags: performance, unix, networking, command-line

This question has been moved to : https://superuser.com/questions/1224389/how-can-i-measure-the-network-traffic-used-by-one-command

I often write :

```
time npm install
```

which will give me as a result :

```
real    0m22.933s
user    0m24.058s
sys     0m3.346s
```

I would like to have the same type of information, but for network consumption.

For example,

```
netmeasure npm install
```

would return :

```
Upload : 499kb
Download : 44MB
```

That would be useful to be able to do "regression tests" on some programs.

Is is possible to get this kind of information with simple unix tools ?

I have already tried `nethogs`, but it is something very interactive, which might be useful if you want to know what is happening on one full unix system, but I'm interested in measuring the network consumption of one command. I'm not looking for an interactive program, but one that will spawn the process for me and wait until it exists to show those statistics.

Comment: I really like this question, but I think it's better off on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I have moved this question here : https://superuser.com/questions/1224389/how-can-i-measure-the-network-traffic-used-by-one-command

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) perhaps with `-e trace=%network` and `-c` or `-C`

Comment: That's already something, but doesn't give the answer in bytes / kbytes